# failed get chat data from firebase to recyclerview

Tags: android, firebase, android-studio, firebase-realtime-database

I'm new to android studio and firebase and now trying to make a simple chat application.

My code can send the chat data to firebase, but failed to get the data back from firebase so nothing updated in the app.

Note:there no crash, just when I type the chat nothing appear in screen.

[image]

Can someone point out where I make it wrong?

Here's my code

**MainActivity**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    RecyclerView recyclerView;
    EditText editText;
    RelativeLayout addBtn;
    DatabaseReference ref;
    FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<ChatMessage,chat_rec> adapter;
    FirebaseRecyclerOptions<ChatMessage> options;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        recyclerView = (RecyclerView)findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
        editText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText);
        addBtn = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.addBtn);

        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        final LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
        linearLayoutManager.setStackFromEnd(true);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);

        ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
        ref.keepSynced(true);

        addBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                String message = editText.getText().toString().trim();

                if (!message.equals("")) {

                    ChatMessage chatMessage = new ChatMessage(message, "user");
                    ref.child("chat").push().setValue(chatMessage);

                }
                editText.setText("");
            }
        });

        Query text = ref.child("chat").limitToLast(100);
        options = new FirebaseRecyclerOptions.Builder<ChatMessage>().setQuery(text, ChatMessage.class).build();

        adapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<ChatMessage, chat_rec>(options) {
            @Override
            protected void onBindViewHolder(chat_rec viewHolder, int position, ChatMessage model) {
                // Bind the Chat object to the ChatHolder
                // ...

                if (model.getMsgUser().equals("user")) {
                    viewHolder.rightText.setText(model.getMsgText());

                    viewHolder.rightText.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    viewHolder.leftText.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }
                else {
                    viewHolder.leftText.setText(model.getMsgText());

                    viewHolder.rightText.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    viewHolder.leftText.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                }

            }

            @Override
            public chat_rec onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
                // Create a new instance of the ViewHolder, in this case we are using a custom
                // layout called R.layout.message for each item
                View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                    .inflate(R.layout.msglist, parent, false);

                return new chat_rec(view);
            }

        };
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
}
```

**chat_rec.java**

```
Public class chat_rec extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder  {
    TextView leftText,rightText;

    public chat_rec(View itemView){
        super(itemView);

        leftText = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.leftText);
        rightText = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.rightText);

    }
}
```

Comment: If the app crashes, there is a stack trace. Please look that up on logcat, and add it to your question.

Comment: If you consider at some point to try using [Cloud Firestore](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/), here you can find a tutorial on how to can create a complete and functional [Chat App](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLn2n4GESV0Ak1HiH0tTPTJXsOEy-5v9qb).

Comment: please do `notifyDataSetChanged();`

Comment: @Rohit i try add `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();` before `recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter)` but the chat still not show up
did i place it wrong?